# GlassFish Cluster change instance when redirect to another application

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, architecture, glassfish

After we deploy **multiple applications** witch are Enreprise application (**ear**) in the server Glassfish that use **Clustering**, and this cluster use **2 Instances** we notify that the cluster change the instance when we navigate to another application, but our goal is to use the same instance because we use Single Sign On (**SSO**) for all the applications.

**N.B**

- When we use one instance and multiple Entreprise application every thing work fine.
- When we use multiple instances and one application also every thing work fine
- When we use multiple application with multiple instances this make a problem.
- When we use **Hight availibility** or **Single-Sign-On State** it work fine, but we don't want to use HA in our System.
- For Apache we use Apache mod_jk or mod_proxy
- GlassFish 3.1.2.2

  > Is there any solution or configuration to fix one instance per user in GlassFish or Apache, this will solve our problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week we found that the problem is in the cookies, so when someone change the application in his Instance, the server Apache create a new cookie for every Entreprise Application with this format :

```
cookiesID.InstanceNBR
```

[image]

Exemple if i use 3 application and 2 Instances, so this can create 3 cookies content like this:

```
cookiesModule1.Instance1
cookiesModule2.Instance2
cookiesModule3.Instance2
```

Because the format of **path** of the cookies is diffirent for each application like this:

```
/erp/module1
/erp/module2
/erp/module3
```

So to solve this problem we specified one Path for all the applications in **web.xml** like this:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <path>/PATH_OF_COOKIES</path>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Because we use SSO for the authentification we use just a **slash /** in the path for all the application:

```
<cookie-config>
    <path>/</path>
</cookie-config>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use sticky sessions, so that requests from a single user are always routed to the same GlassFish instance.

See more info how to configure [here](http://tiainen.sertik.net/2011/03/load-balancing-with-glassfish-31-and.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/gixpx/index.html).

For configuration with NGinx, look [here](http://blog.payara.fish/payara-server-load-balancing-with-nginx) (Payara Server is a supported replacement for GlassFish 4)

Comment: Thank you @OndrejM, i already use sticky sessions, but this also not solve the problem, i found a simple solution for that problem, i will explain it later